# why Rails.application.assets file has &#65279

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm maintain and old code that load css like below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  <%= Rails.application.assets[filename].to_s.html_safe %>
</style>
```

It'd show in browser html like

```
<style type="text/css">
  @charset "UTF-8";
/*
  line 2, xxxx_path
*/
#div1 {
  ...
}

#div2 {
  ...
}
</style>
```

It works fine in local but when on production it shows in browser HTML like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #div1 {...}#div2{...}
</style>
```

and when I edit it as HTML it actually shows:

```
<style type="text/css">
  &#65279;#div1{...}#div2{...}
</style>
```

So it cause css selector is wrong because it seems `&#65279;#div1` instead #div1.
I want to know:

1. How to fix it?
2. why this happened?
3. why we use request to load CSS like `stylesheet_link_tag` will not have this problem?

BTW I tried rake `asset:compile ENV=produciton` still local is working fine.

Comment: This (65279) is the code for a zero-width non-breaking space character.

Comment: Also known as BOM. Check that your CSS file on production is in the correct UTF-8 format and not something else. Check you haven't accidentally got the wrong encoding on any of the files which you can check in the text editor, and then also check any minification or deployment scripts you may have that could convert the text.

Comment: Also see here where a similar issue occurred in the Drupal CMS and has a similar explanation https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1833356

Comment: Thanks, I though it's indeed a encode problem, I decided keep use stylesheet_link_tag in the end for save too much time to solve this!